# pentaho data integration spark-submit with EMR

Tags: apache-spark, pentaho, emr, pentaho-data-integration, spark-submit

I've been reading the documentation to configure spark-submit entry on pentaho DI and the examples are mostly for CDH y HDP, but how does it work for EMR? My specific question is related to the "temporary" nature of EMR clusters. From what i red , you need to copy the *-site.xml files from the cluster to the PDI server, but with every new cluster the hostname changes, and maybe also the *-site.xml files will also change, so with every automatic run or your job you'll need to find out your cluster hostname, and then scp the *-site.xml files to the PDI, am i right? has anybody configured spark-submit entry in PDI with EMR?